# Orgmode: agenda for headlines without any tag

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-tags

Having 'org-agenda-files' set, is there a way to display headlines, which does not have any tags?

E.g 'C-c a' runs 'org-agenda', and then 'M' gives TODO items with specified tag. What if I want TODOs, which does not have any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regular expression in a tags search.  A tag search for `{.*}` will match any tag and conversely, `-{.*}` will no tag.

Comment: Thanks, this method works and does not ignore tag inheritance.

Comment: For anyone searching for how to add a custom agenda command to find these: `("u" "Uncategorized" ((tags-todo "-{.*}")))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do a regexp search on headlines not ending in a colon:

<kbd>C-c a m</kbd> will prompt for a match query. Type `-{:$}` to match headlines not ending in colon. The regular expression goes inside the curly brackets, and the minus sign is for negating the match.

Note that this method ignores tag inheritance.